# Оператор возведения в степень?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть ли в С++ оператор возведения в степень? Можно ли его перегрузить?

Comment: `pow(<число>, <степень>)` - http://cppstudio.com/post/1141/  
В C++, эта функция перегружена в заголовочных файлах `<complex>` и `<valarray>`.

Comment: @entithat так это выходит функция? а есть оператор типа a^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. 
[список операторов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5tk49fh2.aspx), сортированный по возможности перегрузки.